# New SSD (850 Evo) not visible in Device Manager or Explorer (Windows 8/10)

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, diskpart, disk-management

**Scenario and Symptoms**

A brand new Samsung 850 Evo SSD fails to show at all in Disk Management (DiskPart), and consequently cannot be formatted or accessible from Windows Explorer. This is true for both SATA III and USB 3.0 connections.

What is causing this issue and how to resolve it?

---

*Here is a similar question that I do not consider a duplicate (I'm talking about a formatting issue only on a brand new drive, no hardware problems or physical re-flow going on here):*

[SSD appears in BIOS and Device Manager but not in Disk Management or any other tool](https://superuser.com/q/1193369/496260)

Answer (score 1):

This problem may be mistaken as a dead-on-arrival issue, but in this case, it was not. It was a Windows 8/10 bug.

**Explanation**

Disk Management/DiskPart has a bug in Windows 8 and Windows 10 where certain drive formats (exactly which formats I didn't bother to find out) will prevent the entire drive from showing and consequently from being reformatted.

**Solution**

Use a third party formatting tool, or format the drive from an instance of Windows 7 (possibly even a VM). The bug is not present with Windows 7 and you'll be able to see and format the drive.

.

*related threads...*

http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-3311280/ssd-showing-bios-disk-management-device-manager.html

http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-2800267/ssd-showing-disk-management.html

---

**Shared Symptoms**

Although this was the solution in my case, these are non-unique symptoms and they may be the result of other causes, including actual dead-on-arrival and others discussed here...

https://www.easeus.com/storage-media-recovery/ssd-not-showing-up-windows-10.html

Comment: You can also boot a Linux Live disc: I find Debian derivatives have very good device support and [Ubuntu Mate](http://ubuntu-mate.org/download/) should not be too forbidding to a Windows user.